# Shopping cart list removed when new item added

Tags: javascript, html

I have prepared online payment for a printing house, when you click add to cart button total amount of order added to shopping cart. The problem is when you click add to cart button the previous added item is removed.

all is written in js, but I am new in js. How can I keep all items in shopping cart and add new item?

```js
var addToCartButton = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart')
var grandTotal = new Array;
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButton.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButton[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    grandTotal.push(allTotal)
    var cartRowContents = '<table><tr><th>Xidmet adi</th><th>Cemi</th></tr>'
    var buttonClicked = document.getElementById('ulist') // unordered list where list
    var serviceName = document.getElementById('service') // service name from dropdown list
    for (k = 0; k < grandTotal.length; k++) {
      cartRowContents += '<tr><td>' + serviceName.value + '</td><td>' + grandTotal[k] + '</td></tr>'
    }
    buttonClicked.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartRowContents += '</table>'
  })
}
```

```html
<!-- seperator -->

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade right" id="fullHeightModalRight" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-height">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Sifarişlərin siyahısı</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>SİFARİŞLƏRİNİZ</h2>
        <ul id="ulist"></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Bağla</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="odenis">Ödəniş et</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2-->

<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Onlayn ödəmə</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">


  <form class="form-payment" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" id="payment">
    <fieldset>

      <p class="warning" id="warning">Hörmətli müştəri, istəyinizə uyğun sifarişinizi qeyd edin və yekun məbləğin doğruluğundan əmin olduqdan sonra "Təsdiq et" düyməsini sıxın</p>


      <input type="hidden" name="id" />



      <label for="service">Xidmət növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="service" name="service" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Xidmət növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Çap'>Çap</option>
        <option value='Kserokopiya'>Kserokopiya</option>
        <option value='Kitab çapı'>Kitab çapı</option>
        <option value='Diplom və sertifikat çapı'>Diplom və sertifikat çapı</option>
        <option value='Poster çapı'>Poster çapı</option>
        <option value='Skan'>Skan </option>
        <option value='Laminasiya'>Laminasiya</option>
        <option value='Cildləmə'>Cildləmə</option>


      </select>

      <label id="papertypeL" for="papertype">Kağız növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="papertype" name="papertype" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Kağız növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Standart kağız (A4-parlaq)-0.50 AZN'>Standart kağız(A4-parlaq)-0.50 AZN</option>
        <option value='Premium kağız (A4-parlaq)-1 AZN'>Premium kağız (A4-parlaq)-1 AZN</option>
        <option value='VİP kağız (A4-Mat)-1.50 AZN'>VİP kağız (A4-Mat)-1.50 AZN</option>


      </select>



      <label id="scansizeL" for="scansize">Kağız ölçüsü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="scansize" name="scansize" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Ölçünü seçin</option>
        <option value='A4'>A4</option>
        <option value='A3'>A3</option>


      </select>
      <label id="bookprintL" for="bookprint">Kağız ölçüsü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="bookprint" name="bookprint" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Ölçünü seçin</option>
        <option value='A4'>A4</option>
        <option value='A5'>A5</option>


      </select>

      <label id="postersizeL" for="postersize">Poster ölçüsü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="postersize" name="postersize" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Ölçünü seçin</option>

        <option value='A3'>A3</option>
        <option value='A3+'>A3+</option>


      </select>
      <label id="posterpaperL" for="posterpaper">Kağız növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="posterpaper" name="posterpaper" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Kağız növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Standart kağız'>Standart kağız</option>
        <option value='Premium kağız'>Premium kağız</option>
        <option value='VİP kağız'>VİP kağız</option>


      </select>
      <label id="printL" for='print'>Çap növü:</label>

      <label id="radio" class="container-radio">Ağ-qara
          <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="capnovu" value="Ağ-qara" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      <label id="radio" class="container-radio">Rəngli
          <input type="radio" name="capnovu" value="Rəngli" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

      <label id="sideL" for='side'>Üz sayı:</label>
      <label id="side" class="container-radio">Təküzlü
          <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="uzsayi" value="Təküzlü" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      <label id="side" class="container-radio">İkiüzlü
          <input type="radio"  name="uzsayi" value="İkiüzlü" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>


      <label id="kitab-cildL" class="container-radio" for="kitab-cild">Cildləmə<input id="kitab-cild" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" /><span class="checkmark-box"></span></label>
      <label id="cildL" for="cild">Cildləmə növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="cild" name="cild" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Cildləmə növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Plasmas spiral cildləmə'>Plasmas spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Dəmir spiral cildləmə'>Dəmir spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Kleylə cildləmə'>Kleylə cildləmə</option>


      </select>

      <label id="cildA4L" for="cildA4">Cildləmə növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="cildA4" name="cildA4" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Cildləmə növünü seçin</option>

        <option value='Dəmir spiral cildləmə'>Dəmir spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Plasmas spiral cildləmə'>Plasmas spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Kleylə cildləmə'>Kleylə cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Kitab bərpa'>Kitab bərpa</option>
        <option value='Çubuqla cildləmə'>Çubuqla cildləmə</option>


      </select>


      <label id="cildA3L" for="cildA3">Cildləmə növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="cildA3" name="cildA3" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Cildləmə növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Dəmir spiral cildləmə'>Dəmir spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Plasmas spiral cildləmə'>Plasmas spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Çubuqla cildləmə'>Çubuqla cildləmə</option>


      </select>







      <label id="sayL" for="say">Səhifə Sayı:</label><input id="say" name="say" class="form-input" type="text" value="" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
      <label id="nusxeSayL" for="nusxeSay">Nüsxə Sayı:</label><input id="nusxeSay" name="nusxeSay" class="form-input" type="text" value="" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
      <label id="laminasiyaL" class="container-radio">Laminasiya olacaq?
          <input type="checkbox" id="laminasiya"  name="checkbox"  onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark-box"></span>
        </label>
      <label id="deliveryL" class="container-radio">Çatdırılma olacaq?
          <input type="checkbox" id="delivery"  name="checkbox"  onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark-box"></span>
        </label>

      <label id="deliveryRadio" class="container-radio">Bakıdaxili kuryer ilə (3 AZN)
          <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="kuryer" id="kuryer" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      <label id="deliveryRadio" class="container-radio">Bakıdaxili taksi ilə (5 AZN)
          <input type="radio"  name="radio" value="taksi" id="taksi" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      <label id="deliveryRadio" class="container-radio">Bölgələrə poçtla (3 AZN)
          <input type="radio"  name="radio" value="poct" id="poct" onclick="calculateTotal()">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </fieldset>

</div>

<div id="totalPrice" style="padding:10px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#ff0;
            ">
</div>


<div class="modal-footer">


  <button type="submit" name="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Təsdiq et</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default addToCart" id="addToCart" type="button" href="#fullHeightModalRight" data-toggle="modal">Add to Cart</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I added js code for adding to shopping cart, calculation code is omitted. 
P.S. Add to cart button is in another modal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) `buttonClicked.innerHTML = cartRowContents;` will overwrite the contents of buttonClicked every time you run it. Try changing to `+=`. 2)  `cartRowContents += '</table>'`...why are you running this _after_ you've already copied `cartRowContents` into the page? Logically this make no sense...it's too late. Move this line up before the `innerHTML` line.

Comment: `addToCartButton = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart')` ? You don't have any `button` (even any element) with `addToCart` class.

Comment: @ADyson I made your modification 2. But modification 1 gives error when  I change  `=` to `+=`

Comment: @ths I mentioned in the question that addToCart button is in another modal. I didn't want to copy whole modal code for just one button. But if you need I can :)

Comment: @ADyson, I removed var from the beginning the syntax error went but in that case it didn't add to shopping cart at all

Comment: I think it would be better if you add all the necessary code allowing us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @NahidMirzayev why did you add a `var` at all? That was nothing to do with my suggestion! I agree with ths's comment above, it would be a lot easier to help you if we had a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with. Let us know when you've updated your question with that extra code and information. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson  thank you for your efforts to help me. I added code of other modal. Do you need whole index file where Modals are called? I didn't post it here because it is too long and there is nothing with this js

Comment: Can you please make it part of the main code snippet, so that we can actually execute this code, and see the error happening in real time? Thanks.

Comment: P.S. I don't know precisely what other code might be needed - it's your application, so you need to decide. The point of the "minimal reproducible example" is to give just enough code/data/details to allow us to see the error and understand what is happening, but no more than that (so we don't have to deal with irrelevant details). It's a process you have to follow to remove things you think are not related, and re-run the code so it still shows the error. If you remove something which stops the error, then you've gone too far. This process might even help you identify and fix it yourself!

Comment: use appendChild https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild its faster - its cleaner

Comment: @ADyson I tried but it exceeded 30000 characters limit. I will shorten and post it here.

Comment: Your last edit simply made the snippet unrunnable because you moved the HTML into the JavaScript section, for reasons I cannot understand. If you reached a character limit then this definitely indicates you need to reduce your example quite a bit, down to just the **essential** parts